# LEFT JOIN Not return correct result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table in my database

team

```
id game_id name image

26   48     t    t.png
27   48     t2   t2.png
```

score

```
id  team_id  score

1   26       5
2   26       14
```

my query

```
SELECT t.id,t.name,t.image,sum(s.score) 
  FROM `team` AS t 
  LEFT JOIN score s ON (s.team_id=t.id) where t.game_id=48
```

my query always give one team that is team 26

but it will be like

```
id  name image     score

26  t    t.png     19
27  t2   t2.png    null
```

I cant understand what wrong in my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a GROUP BY clause. Try this query.

```
SELECT t.id, t.name, t.image, sum(s.score) as total_score 
FROM `team` AS t 
LEFT JOIN `score` s ON (s.team_id = t.id) 
WHERE t.game_id=48 
GROUP BY t.id, t.name, t.image
```

Comment: Why do you think that the condition should be moved?

Comment: @ypercube OK, agreed. That's not needed. I thought team 27 has no game id 48 in the team table.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t.id,t.name,t.image,sum(s.score)
FROM `team` AS t 
LEFT JOIN score s 
ON (s.team_id=t.id)
where t.game_id=48 
group by t.id
```

Just add `group by` clause in it

Comment: t.id or s.team_id both are ok as both have same values

Answer (score 1):

You have aggregated the scores, so what your query will do is to combine the the scores for your two teams, if you want to return it on 2 separated results. you must put GROUP BY t.id

```
SELECT t.id,t.name,t.image,sum(s.score) FROM `team` AS t
 LEFT JOIN score s ON (s.team_id=t.id) 
where t.game_id=48 GROUP BY t.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Group by will solve your problem:

```
SELECT t.id,t.name,t.image,sum(s.score) 
FROM `team` AS t 
LEFT JOIN score s ON (s.team_id=t.id and t.game_id=48) 
GROUP BY t.id
```